# To get more than 5 reviews from google places API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

I am doing  an application where I extract the google reviews using google places API.When I read the document related to it in "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places",I found out that I could get only 5 top reviews.Is there any option to get more reviews.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google places API returning only 5 results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785537/google-places-api-returning-only-5-results)

Answer (score 23):

In order to have access to more than 5 reviews with the Google API you have to purchase Premium data Access from Google. 
That premium plan will grant you access to all sorts of additional data points you have to shell out a pretty penny.

If you are a Business owner wanting to retrieve all of your reviews, you can do so but first you have to get verified and could do this through the MyBusiness API more info here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/

Comment: This is correct, you can retrieve all reviews if you're the business owner using Google My Business API. https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

Comment: As a Business owner we can  get all reviews through the MyBusiness API  https://developers.google.com/my-business/. As a application (third party) we can get the reviews by places api. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=diecalp&key=yakyakyak with limit of 5. So premium plan with places api  we able to get the all reviews with respect to their place. right? @tekill

Comment: @Nidhin can you select the answer, as this has been answered. Thank you I hope you were able to accomplish what you set out to do.

Comment: Looks like they stopped supporting new customers. "Note: The Google Maps Platform Premium Plan is no longer available for sign up or new customers." Any alternative?

Answer (score 18):

There is a feature request for that: [Issue 7630: Response to Include More Than 5 Reviews](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7630) ─ I'd recommend you "star" it to receive updates.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no way to get more than 5 reviews in the places API unless you are the business owner after getting verified as Tekill said.
But it looks like there are some external services that can get all the reviews. My guess is that they scrape them from Google Maps directly:
Some of these services are [Wextractor](https://wextractor.com) and [ReviewShake](https://www.reviewshake.com/)

Comment: These are not helpful. And also not returning all reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a third party solution like SerpApi to scrape all the reviews of any place. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Each page fatches 10 results. To implement the pagination just use the `start` parameter which defines the result offset (e.g., `0` (default) is the first page of results, `10` is the 2nd page of results, `20` is the 3rd page of results, etc.)

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google_maps_reviews",
  "place_id": "0x89c259a61c75684f:0x79d31adb123348d2",
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
reviews = results['reviews']
```

Example output:

```json
"reviews": [
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Waylon Bilbrey",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/107691056156160235121?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUituIlpTvAhVYCc0KHbvTCrgQvvQBegQIARAx",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjOj6Wjfk1kSYjhvH7WIBNMdl4nPj6FvUhvYcR6=s40-c0x00000000-cc-rp",
      "reviews": 1
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "date": "a week ago",
    "snippet": "I've been here multiple times. The coffee itself is just average to me. The service is good (the people working are nice). The aesthetic is obviously what brings the place some fame. A little overpriced (even for NY). A very small cup for $6 where I feel like the price comes from the top rainbow foam decor , when I'm going to cover it anyways. If it's for an insta pic then it may be worth it?"
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Amber Grace Sale",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106390058588469541899?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUituIlpTvAhVYCc0KHbvTCrgQvvQBegQIARA7",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj84nHu_9V_0V4yRbZcr-8ZTYAHua6gUBP8fC7W=s40-c0x00000000-cc-rp-ba3",
      "local_guide": true,
      "reviews": 33,
      "photos": 17
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "date": "2 years ago",
    "snippet": "They really take pride in their espresso roast here and the staff is extremely knowledgeable on the subject. It’s also a GREAT place to do work although a table is no guarantee; you might have to wait for a bit. My almond milk cappuccino was very acidic at the end which wasn’t expected but I could still tell the bean was high quality. Their larger lattés they put in a tall glass cup which looks really really cool. Would definitely go again.",
    "likes": 2,
    "images": [
      "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMup24_dHrWtNN4ZD70EPsiRMf_tykcUkPw6A1H=w100-h100-p-n-k-no"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Kelvin Petar",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100859090874785206875?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUituIlpTvAhVYCc0KHbvTCrgQvvQBegQIARBG",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhdIvUDamzfPqbYIpwhnGJV2XWSi77iVXfEsiKS=s40-c0x00000000-cc-rp",
      "reviews": 3
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "date": "3 months ago",
    "snippet": "Stumptown Cafe is the perfect place to work or catch up with friends. Never too loud, never too dead. Their lattes and deliciously addicting and the toasts are tasty as well. Wifi is always fast, which is a huge plus! The staff are the friendliest, I highly recommend this place!"
  },
  ...
]
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-reviews-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Is there any chance my server API gets blocked by Google or Yelp when using SerpApi? If there is, how do I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @miguev, there's at the moment no way to get more than 5 top reviews without using premium APIs (according to a Google Maps guy I had a talk with) and that's pricey.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to sign for The Google Maps Platform Premium Plan to show them on pages like [this](https://tarta.ai/p/_G2X_IABa_lfHxJ2DlkW) but Google said it's no longer available for sign up or new customers. Right now we're limited to 5 reviews only.