# Get all google review

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I want to know about google review which we want to fetch from google api .
currently is it showing only five review at a time .|
please help me out from this how can I get all the review from goole API or something else which is used to fetch that review from google location

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To get more than 5 reviews from google places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223719/to-get-more-than-5-reviews-from-google-places-api)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help. It is recommended that you do some researching first.