How to get more than 5 reviews returned from Google Places API (New)?
I have not found any modern solution or answer to this question: how to fetch more than 5 reviews from business page with Google Places API (new). When I asked this from some AI's, they said there is pagination possibility, but I can't find a way to make it work. So is this pagination real thing or not?
I was trying to make a project where I fetch reviews from a popular statue for example. I was developing this with HTML, CSS and vanilla JavaScript (node.js, express). But I just haven't found any real answers to this. I am always getting only 5 reviews rendered.
app.get('/api/google-reviews', async (req, res) => {
const GOOGLE_PLACE_ID = 'PLACE_ID';
const API_KEY = 'KEY';
const pageToken = req.query.pageToken || '';

const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${GOOGLE_PLACE_ID}&fields=reviews,user_ratings_total&key=${API_KEY}&pagetoken=${pageToken}`;

try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    
    if (data.result) {
        const totalReviews = data.result.user_ratings_total || 0;
        const reviews = data.result.reviews || [];
        const nextPageToken = data.next_page_token || null;

        res.json({
            reviews: reviews,
            totalReviews: totalReviews,
            nextPageToken: nextPageToken
        });
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'No reviews found' });
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching reviews:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch reviews' });
}

});

This question is similar to: To get more than 5 reviews from google places API. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223719/to-get-more-than-5-reviews-from-google-places-api
